# In optimum control, what is intended by discrete scaling?

Tags: optimization, optimal-control

I have been looking for strategies to solve my optimal control problem as it is severely suffering from scaling issues. I then came across this article (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.11073.pdf) and it mentions that rather than scaling the problem at the "discrete level", one should scale at the optimum control level.

It seems a little cryptic at first but my intuition is that by discrete level scaling we mean that all inputs, that is all parameters of the optimum control problem that have units are scaled with respect to scaling factors that we choose. This means that if we have a problem where $\bf{x}$ is our vector of state variables, the starting values to the problem would be

$\tilde{\bf{x}}=\bf{SF} \bigotimes \bf{x}$

where $\bf{SF}$ is our vector of scaling factors.

Is this what the article is referring to as "discrete level" scaling?

Comment: Could elaborate on which part of the paper you are referring to? Namely, after skimming through it I could not find the equation you have written out in your question.

Comment: Sure- on page 2 it says "Our analysis also reveals another surprising result: that if scaling is performed at the discrete level, it inadvertently introduces new terms in the dynamical equations with possible feedback effects that may
destabilize the search algorithm". The equation that I used is not written in their article but is what I am assuming they refer to as discrete level scaling. Equation 36 and 37 give you the closest intepretation to this where the variable with the tilde is the scaled unit.

Comment: I believe discrete scaling is discussed in section "C. Fallacy of Discrete Scaling", which starts on page 18.

Comment: From what I gathered, discrete level scaling just refers to scaling an optimal control problem with different scaling factors for each discretized node, or "time step". What I don't understand is, by their same logic, how in page 15 "Illustrating a process for better balancing" the convention of scaling not with respect to the units of the states but rather with respect to each state. If you don't adhere to the same units of scaling across different states, aren't you introducing extra dynamics to the problem? Perhaps I should open a new question and focus on this instead.

Comment: As discussed in "C. Fallacy of Discrete Scaling" just using a static gain for each state doesn't introduce new dynamics. However, using time varying gains (both a scalar gain for all states at once or each state separately) can introduce additional dynamics.

Comment: This is what I don't get. Intuitively, if a state is composed of the units of another state, than the gains should also be factors or products of the gains of the other state. For example, if your state of position is in meters, and the future state of position is dependent on the current and future discretized velocities, than those velocities must be in meters per whatever time unit you are using. What the paper suggests instead is that this does not matter and you can in fact consider different units of scaling for the different states. I don't see how this can give you a realistic solutio